# Ethereum Clique RPC Call | web3.clique undefined issue

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, poa, clique

To access the functionality of Clique through geth javascript console is easy, like `clique.getSnapshot(), clique.propose("address",bool)` etc.
But I'm not able to access those functionality using **RPC call** through **web3**. When I'm trying using `web3.clique.getSnapshot()` I'm getting error as  **`can not read property of undefined`**. Is there any way out to use those functionality?

Answer (score 3):

clique API is a geth specific extension. You can enable this with `--rpcapi clique`

Then you can send the corresponding JSON RPC calls.

E.g.

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"clique_getSnapshot","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545

curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"clique_getSigners","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
```

For the list of available methods see https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/web3ext/web3ext.go (Search for Clique_JS).

AFAIK web3 library will not have the clique objects available, since it's geth specific.